# can a scheduled Cron job in Linux server run on every 1st day of the month and also on a specific day of the week

Tags: shell, scripting

Below cron entries show how to execute tasks on 1st day of the month and also on every Tuesday.

```
00 02 1 * * - This will execute on every first day of the month.

00 02 * * 2 - This will restart the script every week (Tuesday).
```

Can a single cron entry replace these two above separate schedules? or do we need two separate schedules always to achieve the same?

If I have a use case to restart the script on 1st of every month and also on every Tuesday,  it would be helpful if I can replace those two entries with one
.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is **yes**... [**man 5 crontab**](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) explains:

> Commands are executed by `cron(8)` when the `'minute', 'hour', and
>   'month of the year'` fields match the current time, **and at least
>   one** of the two `'day' fields ('day of month',  or 'day of week')`
>   match the current time.

Where the order is:

> ```
>     field          allowed values
>     -----          --------------
>     minute         0-59
>     hour           0-23
>     day of month   1-31
>     month          1-12 (or names, see below)
>     day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sunday, or use names)
> ```

Your `minute`, `hour` and `month` fields are always the same `0 2 _ * _`. You want to execute your script on either the 1<sup>st</sup>-day of the month `_ _ 1 _ _` or Tuesday (day 2) `_ _ _ _ 2`. Neither are mutually exclusive.

Since the crontab will run when either `'day of month'`,  or `'day of week'` match the current time, you may combine them for the result you want, e.g.

```
0 2 1 * 2 your_command
```

Which will run at 2am on either the 1<sup>st</sup>-day of the month or every Tuesday.